# How to specify that Quiet should silence foo::shdw messages for ANY symbol foo?

Tags: message-coding

I have some package code that does rather complex multi-context evaluation, and I *know* it's going to throw warnings about shadowed symbols. The shadowing isn't actually a problem. For the end-user's sake, I want to suppress these warnings.

`Quiet` can suppress all messages, which is too heavy-handed. Other kinds of messages might be important and should be reported.

`Quiet` can also suppress specific named messages, which is too precise. I don't want to name the specific symbols that might be shadowed, for two reasons: I can't necessarily predict them, and naming the symbols explicitly adds their names to a context that only exacerbates the shadowing problem.

What I would really like to do is to call `Quiet[stuffToEvaluate,{*::shdw}]` in order to suppress the shadowing message for any symbol, but *Mathematica* doesn't seem to accept a wildcard there. None of the message groups listed in `$MessageGroups` is helpful, either.

Any suggestions, o sages?

Comment: Can't you just avoid the shadowing? The shadowing issues typically indicate the problems with design of the code, and can be avoided. OTOH, these problems, if not taken care of, can lead to pretty nasty surprises, so I'd hesitate to just silence them.

Comment: There's `Off` and `On` with `General::shdw`, which might work; but I second Leonid's concerns.

Comment: I hear you, but trying to get rid of the shadowing warnings has been something like playing whack-a-mole; getting my code to work AT ALL in *Mathematica*'s messed-up namespace system has been a nightmare. Long term, I'm going to try using a sandboxed sub-process with `LinkCreate` to avoid these problems, but that will take some time to figure out and my students need a new assignment yesterday.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Michael's suggestion to use `Off` and `On` with `General::shdw` will be one solution to your problem - if you really decide to go down this road (which is what we recommended against in comments). But, just for the record, it is not difficult to implement one's own version of `Quiet`, that would be more selective.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
ClearAll[selectiveQuiet];
selectiveQuiet[symPattern_, msgPattern_] :=
  Function[
    code
    ,
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
      Module[{inMsg, quiet},
        Block[{quiet},
          SetAttributes[quiet, HoldAll];
          quiet[Verbatim[MessageName][symPattern, msgPattern], ___] :=
             Function[c, Null, HoldAll];
          quiet[x_, ___] := # &;
          Unprotect[Message];
          (call : Message[args___]) /; ! TrueQ[inMsg] :=
            Block[{inMsg = True},
              quiet[args][call]
            ];
          Protect[Message];
          code
        ]]]
    ,
    HoldAll
  ];
```

In your case, you would use it as

```
selectiveQuiet[_, "shdw"][your-code]
```

But the function `selectiveQuiet` is much more general, of course. For example:

```
selectiveQuiet[Part, _][Range[5][[10]]]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[10]] *)
```

Note that there are subtle but important differences between `Quiet` and `selectiveQuiet`. Basically, while `Quiet` silences messages, `selectiveQuiet` suppresses them entirely. In particular, `Check` behaves differently when used inside `Quiet` or `selectiveQuiet`:

```
selectiveQuiet[Power, _][Check[1/0, $Failed]]

(* ComplexInfinity *)
```

while

```
Quiet @ Check[1/0, $Failed] 

(* $Failed *)
```

For the case at hand, `selectiveQuiet` may have advantages over `On` -`Off` method, because it doesn't redefine the global state - the behavior of `Message` is only changed for the code you run inside of `selectiveQuiet`, and there is no danger to affect any other code or forget to set the messages `On` again.